# Populating an ArrayList with multiple object types

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create an ArrayList with multiple object types in Java. So far I have

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DragRace {
    public class Dragsters {

        public String name;
        public double rTime;
        public int torque;
        public double traction;
        public int burnout;
    }

    ArrayList<Dragsters> dragsterList = new ArrayList<Dragsters>();
    dragsterList.add("one", 0.6, 1000, 0.9, 3);
```

But it gives me the error

```
cannot resolve symbol 'add.'
```

I have searched on Google but could not find an answer that could be used in what I'm doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You appear to be expecting the list to handle object construction for you, which [it will not do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29). Construct a `Dragsters` object first, then pass it in and see.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot have statements inside a class but outside a method, constructor, or initializer block.  Put that code in `main`.

Second, call `new Dragsters()`, not `"one", 0.6, 1000, 0.9, 3`.  Java will not take arguments, deduce the type (`Dragster`), create an object of that type, and automatically assign them to instance variables in the order in which they're declared.  There is no such `add` method in `ArrayList` that takes those 5 arguments.

Third, if you do want to pass those values when creating a `Dragster`, then create a constructor in `Dragsters` that will take 5 parameters and explicitly assign them to its instance variables.

Comment: Just want to add that calling your class `Dragsters` (plural) suggests a misunderstanding of how classes in Java work. The class is like a blueprint that each object is made from. It's not all of your objects together.

Answer (score 0):

dragsterList.add(new Dragsters("one", 0.6, 1000, 0.9, 3));

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @rgettman. The revised code would look like below.

```
public class DragRace {
    public class Dragsters {
         Dragsters(String name, double rTime, int torque, double traction, int burnout){

        this.name = name;
        this.rTime = rTime;
        this.torque = torque;       
        this.traction = traction;
        this.burnout = burnout;
    }

    String name;
    int burnout double rTime;
    int burnout int torque;
    int burnout double traction;
    int burnout int burnout;
}

ArrayList<Dragsters> dragsterList = new ArrayList<Dragsters>();
dragsterList.add(new Dragsters("one", 0.6, 1000, 0.9, 3));
```